# why do I see deleted packages tooltips in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I'm practicing creating packages and I've installed and uninstalled packages a lot, but I still see some deleted packages

[image]

Although in reality they no longer exist

[image]

How to make non-existent packages disappear from tooltips

Comment: I suspect RStudio is caching what packages it has seen so that it doesn't do a filesystem-scan every time you look at that. Have you restarted RStudio since deleting the package(s)? (I don't know if there's a way to convince it to rescan.)

Comment: Maybe they vanish using e.g. `unloadNamespace('exampleRcpp')`.

Comment: 1) yes, I restarted RStudio

2) `unloadNamespace('exampleRcpp')` did not work

Comment: You should probably report a bug to RStudio: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues